# std::async function running serially

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, future

When using std::async with launch::async in a for loop, my code runs serially in the same thread, as if each async call waits for the previous before launching. In the notes for std::async references ([std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async))), this is possible if the std::future is not bound to a reference, but that's not the case with my code. Can anyone figure out why it's running serially?

Here is my code snippet:

```
class __DownloadItem__ { //DownloadItem is just a "typedef shared_ptr<__DownloadItem__> DownloadItem"
    std::string buffer;
    time_t last_access;
 std::shared_future<std::string> future;
}

for(uint64_t start: chunksToDownload){
        DownloadItem cache = std::make_shared<__DownloadItem__>();
        cache->last_access = time(NULL);
        cache->future =
                std::async(std::launch::async, &FileIO::download, this, api,cache, cacheName, start, start + BLOCK_DOWNLOAD_SIZE - 1);
     }
}
```

The future is being stored in a shared future because multiple threads might be waiting on the same future.

I'm also using GCC 6.2.1 to compile it.

Comment: Do note editing your question to change the code you "have" after you get answers is not kosher as it can/may invalidate answers you revived in good faith.  In this case though it appears that it does not and you have the same issue.  The `cache` you add to the containers is not the `cache` that has the future stored in it.

Comment: I believe `std::shared_future` is for multiple threads waiting on **one** result whereas I think you need one thread waiting on multiple results. Maybe you need `std::vector<std::future>`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I will try to keep that in mind next time

Comment: @Galik I do have multiple threads waiting on the same result. They are stored in a map so that multiple threads don't try to do the same work.

Comment: @NathanOliver I misunderstood your comment. I actually don't understand why you say that the `cache` variable is not the same `cache` in the container if `cache` is a `shared_ptr`. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Is it possible that your `FileIO::download` does some locking internally? because the current code shouldn't block by itself

Comment: @thejinx0r Sorry about that.  I missed that it is a `shared_ptr`.  That means your edit did invalidate the answers.

Comment: @krzaq I don't think so. But maybe, I do call a `cache->future.wait()` in another thread, but it shouldn't be concurrent with the launch. There are no mutexes in the download section.

Comment: I rolled back the edit on your question as it invalidated all three answers you have.  You can ask a new question with the complete information to get more help.

Comment: @NathanOlivier. Ok, will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `std::future` returned by `async` blocks in the destructor.  That means when you reach the `}` of

```
for(uint64_t start: chunksToDownload){
    DownloadItem cache = std::make_shared<__DownloadItem__>();
    cache->last_access = time(NULL);
    cache->future =
            std::async(std::launch::async, &FileIO::download, this, api,cache, cacheName, start, start + BLOCK_DOWNLOAD_SIZE - 1);
 }  // <-- When we get here
```

`cache` is destroyed which in turn calls the destructor of`future` which waits for the thread to finish.

What you need to do is store each `future` returned from `async` in a separate persistent `future` that is declared outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

That's a misfeature of `std::async` as defined by C++11. Its futures' destructors are special and wait for the operation to finish. More detailed info on [Scott's Meyers](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2013/03/stdfutures-from-stdasync-arent-special.html) blog.

`cache` is being destroyed at the end of each loop iteration, thereby calling destructors of its subobjects.

Use [`packaged_task`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) or ensure you keep a container of copies of shared pointers to your `cache` to avoid waiting for the destructors. Personally, I'd go with `packeged_task`

Comment: Why would the destructor be called if I am storing it? That's the part I don't understand.

Comment: "Its futures' destructors are special"; it's funny because the article you linked is called "std::futures from std::async _aren't_ special! "

Comment: @thejinx0r edited. `cache`, which keeps your future, lives only inside the loop, so it gets destroyed at the end of each iteration.

Comment: @krzaq Right, I didn't think it was relevant, but I was storing them in a std::map and a std::set. I updated the code. Even with the storage, it was still running serailly.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall It's a good writeup. The title suggests you could try to apply a different mental model than the current consensus is, but if you agree with that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed yourself, the `future` d-tor of `future` returned by `std::async` blocks and waits for the async operation to finish (for the `future` to become `ready`).
In your case, `cache` object goes out of scope at each of the loop iterations and thus gets destructed, together with the `future` it holds, so you see the mentioned effect.